# nVidia Control Panel Won't Recognize SLI

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

So yesterday I bought a brand new, 1,000W PSU to replace my 650W one and to allow for SLI. I install it and my second card (both are GTX 560 ti cards). I reinstalled my drivers and my system recognizes both cards. The control panel says "GTX 560 ti x2", I can select between them for Physx, sound output, picture output (although I only have one hooked up to my monitor), etc. But the kicker is I can't turn on SLI. Everything I've read says I'll get a balloon notification saying I can use SLI and the control panel will have a new section, etc, but none of those things happens. Anyone have any ideas?

System:
Win7 Professional x64
2x GTX 560 ti
3.1 GHz Intel Core i5
1,000W Xion PSU
8GB RAM
(Can't think of my motherboard right now)

Note: My PSU and MOBO both say they're SLI certified and I'm using an SLI bridge.

Edit: Formatting changes

Comment: Check your BIOS settings.  Some motherboards need SLI enabled in BIOS.

Comment: I looked around for that in the BIOS and in the manual for the MOBO. Nothing in the manual, no settings that seemed relevant in the BIOS.

Comment: Would need your motherboard info to check, it may need a BIOS update.

Comment: It's only a few months old, but I'll definitely look into that after work.

Comment: Have you checked the firmware and driver versions?

Answer (score 0):

Flash bios. Use the Q Flash utility on Gigabyte bios. You will have to download the newer bios on a USB and then head to the Q Flash utility in bios. For asus mb use the same technics but in TOOLS-EZ-Flash. Also always be sure to download the latest bios for your mboard, you can check (you NEED to check) your bios version inside the bios(the only way i know). And Why do you need SLI in a server?

Comment: How do you know it's a gigabyte motherboard? These instructions won't work for everyone